# Mean value and binomial distribution. How do I express it mathematical?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am actually testing bit sequences (so just '0' and '1') on statistical properties. If i have a random bit sequence each bit is a bernoulli experiment and the sequence is therefore binomial distributed with p=0.5. For example if i have a sequence with length n=100, the probability that there are exactly k=50 '1' in the bitstream is given by the binomial pmf with these values.

Now I take the mean values of such a bit sequence and want to display this mean value in the same graph as the binomial distribution. So i "norm" the pmf by dividing the values of the x-axes (the k) by the length of the bitstream. Alternatively i could not use the mean value but just sum up the bits and show it in the same graph as the binomial pmf, which would be mathematically correct, but not the way i want to show it.

How can i express what i did there by 'norming' the x-axes of the binomial pmf mathematically?

[Example for the mean values on the 'normed' binomial distribution with n=4096 and p=0.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5PjL.png)

[And the corresponding 'real' binomial distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ST8P.png)

Comment: Can you show an example of your graphical display?

Comment: Alright! I edited the OP and added two pictures so you hopefully can see what i mean.

Comment: OK, thanks. Much clearer. My opinion is that your first figure (with red asterisks) is ok if you label the horiz axis as 'binomial proportions', the usual terminology when counts of 'successes' (your 1's) are divided by total number of 'trials' (length of bitstream). I do not believe the way you are using 'normed' matches usual terminology. (A regrettably growing tendency is to use 'normed' anytime something is divided by something else, and thus the word becomes meaningless.)

Answer (score 0):

When you plot the pmf of the binomial distribution (i.e. probability vs. $ k $), you are plotting the probability of obtaining $ k $ successful outcomes in your $ n$ Bernoulli experiments. That is the second figure in your question.

When you divide the pmf of the binomial distribution by the length of the bitstream (i.e. by $ n $), you are converting the x-axis to a proportional measure (that lies between 0 and 1). That is the first figure in your question. Instead of counting the number of successful outcomes, you are counting the proportion of successful outcomes (out of $ n $).

You can also think about this in another way... Let $ X_1, ... , X_n $ be $ n $ independent Bernoulli random variables. Then you can use the central limit theorem to approximate the distribution of $ \bar{X_n} $ (i.e. the sum of $ X_1, ... , X_n $ divided by $ n $):

$$ \sqrt{n} \times \frac{\bar{X_n} - \mu}{\sigma} \approx N(0,1) \rightarrow \bar{X_n} \approx N \Big( \mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n} \Big)  $$